# Query returning wrong at Alter

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query, outline of the query is such that I want to  drop the current primarykey and change the primary key to another column in a table called Customer and I am starting with the check first if the values in the column are unique. And the steps that follow are

-Check if the new primary key column has any null values

-As the earlier primary key is also foreign key in another table drop that Constraint

-Drop the primary key column in the Customer table

-Create the new primarykey in the Customer table which is id

-Also add the same column in Rental Table as it has Foreign key constraint as mentioned before

-Re-add the Foreign Key constraint in the Rental table.

```
select case when count(distinct id)= count(id)
then 
(

-- How to check for any nulls in the column id

ALTER TABLE dbo.Rental DROP CONSTRAINT FK_CustNo_Rental
Go

Alter Table dbo.Customer DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Customer
GO

Alter Table dbo.Customer DROP COLUMN [CustNo]
GO

Alter Table dbo.Customer ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY (id)
GO

Alter Table dbo.Rental ADD COLUMN [id] [nvarchar](9)    NOT NULL
GO

Alter Table dbo.Rental ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CustId_Rental FOREIGN KEY([id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([id]),

)

 else 'column values are NOT unique' end
from dbo.Customer;
```

I am unsure on how to check for any null values in the table for the new primary key column and also I am getting error at the first 'Alter'.

Comment: Your query is not at all self-explanatory.  `go` and `alter table` are definitely not part of the syntax for `select`.  You probably want `if` without a `select` for the logic.

Comment: Why not just update the particular column with `where col is null` and then ALTER?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Update with more details.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Is this really something that you want to do multiple times?  It seems like a one-time operation and you can run the code step by step to make the changes you want (or alternatively create a new table with the right format and just insert the data into it).

Comment: The new column which you want to convert may have null and so making it PK will fail. So, before making it PK update that column saying `update tab set newcol = someval where newcol is null` and then make it as PK. Also, as @GordonLinoff pointed, you should try pulling the entire logic in a stored procedure and use `if .. else` condition construct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no just a one time thing, yes I can run step by step, but actually would like to automate it as I have lot of databases with similar kind of requirement. So running the whole thing in one query is kind of important, but I do understand your concern.

Comment: @Rahul the column id is by default already set to Not Null. For me the first statement is basically a starting point to get an entry for the following statements to execute.